# Compressing part of the y-axis (Different scaling for two parts of the y-axis)

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I am looking to plot six data sets on the same plot, in which two of the data sets (shown below in the red solid and red dashed lines) reach a much lower value on the y-axis than that of two of the other data sets (shown in black solid and black dashed lines).

Looking at and presenting the actual shape of the data set curves on the log-log scale is important, and I want to be able to better clearly show the shape of the curve for the black data sets, but the red data sets, (since they reach such a low y value), make it difficult to see.

```
lowx = 0.001;
maxx = Automatic;
lowy = Automatic;
maxy = Automatic;
Show[ListLogLogPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6},PlotRange -> {{lowx, maxx}, {lowy, maxy}}, ImageSize -> 72*9.1, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Red, Dashed}, Blue, {Blue, Dashed}, Black, {Black, Dashed}}, Joined -> True]]
```

(data sets are lists with dimensions {16,2})

[image]

Is there any way to compress portion of the y-axis from ~0 to 0.001 (approx 6 ticks) to be approximately the size of the ~0 to 10^-6 region on the y-axis (approx 3 ticks)? This would also preferably expand the old 0.001 to 1 region on the y-axis to 6 ticks instead of just 3.

I attached a hand-drawn estimation of what I am intending the y-axis to look like. The actual number of ticks for each region does not matter so much, I am just mostly looking to compress down the ~0 to 0.001 region.

[image]

Thanks!

If you want the actual data sets:

```
data1 = {{0.0011, 1.1}, {0.0042, 0.92}, {0.018, 0.53}, {0.025, 0.34}, {0.05, 0.006}{0.10, 7.4*10^-8}, {0.18, 8.9*10^-8}, {0.21, 2.9*10^-8}, {0.38, 5.9*10^-7}, {0.75, 1.9*10^-8}, {1.3, 1.7*10^-8}, {2.3, 2.3*10^-8}, {4.6, 1.2*10^-8}, {9.6, 1.5*10^-8}, {17, 1.1*10^-8}, {28, 1.1*10^-8}};
data2 = {{0.0011, 0.81}, {0.0042, 0.49}, {0.011, 0.16}, {0.025, 0.21}, {0.050, 0.0074}, {0.11, 0.00077}, {0.18, 0.00016}, {0.20, 0.00010}, {0.37, 0.000040}, {0.78, 0.000013}, {1.2, 9.56*10^-6}, {2.35, 6.3*10^-6}, {4.4, 4.2*10^-6}, {9.5, 1.2*10^-6}, {18, 1.2*10^-6}, {29, 6.9*10^-7}};
data3 = {{0.0012, 1.0}, {0.0041, 0.85}, {0.012, 0.89}, {0.024, 0.85}, {0.056, 0.64}, {0.11, 0.29}, {0.17, 0.13}, {0.20, 0.10}, {0.36, 0.046}, {0.77, 0.012}, {1.2, 0.0064}, {2.4, 0.0012}, {4.3, 0.00022}, {9.3, 0.000032}, {18, 0.000028}, {28, 0.000033}};
data4 = {{0.0012, 0.89}, {0.0041, 0.57}, {0.010, 0.311}, {0.025, 0.17}, {0.058, 0.11}, {0.10, 0.11}, {0.18, 0.089}, {0.21, 0.079}, {0.38, 0.069}, {0.77, 0.062}, {1.2, 0.046}, {2.3, 0.038}, {4.1, 0.041}, {9.8, 0.033}, {16, 0.032}, {27, 0.027}};
data5 = {{0.0011, 0.93}, {0.0041, 0.93}, {0.010, 0.97}, {0.023, 0.97}, {0.054, 0.93}, {0.11, 0.89}, {0.18, 0.86}, {0.20, 0.86}, {0.38, 0.86}, {0.79, 0.67}, {1.2, 0.55}, {2.3, 0.43}, {4.1, 0.38}, {9.8, 0.34}, {18, 0.26}, {30, 0.26}};
data6 = {{0.0013, 0.96}, {0.0037, 0.89}, {0.012, 0.78}, {0.028, 0.69}, {0.053, 0.59}, {0.12, 0.64}, {0.18, 0.64}, {0.20, 0.64}, {0.36, 0.57}, {0.77, 0.54}, {1.3, 0.54}, {2.4, 0.50}, {4.3,0.54}, {9.3, 0.46}, {19, 0.48}, {34, 0.50}};
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! This is certainly possible (you need to write a custom scaling function and give it as a parameter [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) to ``ListPlot``). However, I think that from a data visualization point, your approach might be slightly confusing (and also misleading if you don't very explicitly mention this unusual rescaling). Have you considered using [two different y-axes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html)? Or perhaps a smaller inset plot with just the black curve?